# Material Icons not displaying on Azure hosted Vue/Quasar web app

Tags: css, vue.js, azure-web-app-service, quasar-framework, material-icons

I have a webapp created using Vue and Quasar. In my `quasar-user-options.js` file I have added the required icon imports.

```js
import '@quasar/extras/material-icons/material-icons.css'
import "@quasar/extras/material-icons-outlined/material-icons-outlined.css";
```

When developing locally, the icons are displayed fine. It is when the web application is deployed to an Azure App Service when the icons appear as text.

[image]

I have attempted to add the required `@font-face` and `googleMaterialIcons.woff2` file as necessary to the application, but am unsure where it should be (or if it's the correct solution at all). Any suggestions/ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [App Service Sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) will block you from installing custom fonts. The workaround is [migrating your app to a container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-custom-container?pivots=container-windows&tabs=azure-cli) where you can leverage the image to install and configure the custom font.